# Forming and styling a proper dialog or alert like box with React-native modal

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I want to make a general dialog box with the help of react native modal.
I have made the code as follows:

```
<Modal isVisible={isModalVisible} style={styles.modalStyle} >                                      
   <Text>Hello World!</Text>                               
</Modal>
```

And below the style is mentioned:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    modalStyle : {
      top                   : '50%',
      left                  : '50%',
      right                 : 'auto',
      bottom                : 'auto',
      marginRight           : '-50%',

    },
}
```

But the modal dialog is consuming the whole screen!

I have also tried editing the code to :

```
<Modal>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, top: 50%, left: 50%, width: 70%, height : 50% }}>
       <Text>Hello World!</Text>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

removing the style in the Modal.
But still the same result!

Comment: Did you try with `width:height/3` `height:height/3` where height is fetched from `Dimensions`library of `react-native`.

Comment: Also you can check `presentationStyle` prop of the `Modal`. For more see [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal#presentationstyle).

Comment: What is the type of this modal ? I means is this react native default modal or react-native-community 's modal or other ?

Comment: @KishanBharda it's the react native default modal

Comment: @avanikothari okay trying that

Comment: I suggest you to use https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox. It has more style flexibility. @Mohor

Answer (score 0):

In-Built Modal of `react-native` is sometimes difficult to customise. There is this awesome library I have used number of times. See [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal).

Answer (score 0):

I've used react native modal , and to show the modal partially , what i did is , where the height is 100, so you can cutsomise the height

```
<Modal isVisible={true} style={{justifyContent: "flex-end"}} >
<View style={{height:100}}>
</View>
</Modal>
```

now , try once. and letme know if this works. coz it works for me. otherwise ill alter it.